# How to automate a vnc+ssh solution

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, vnc

I would like to run an application (call it firefox) on my work machine.  The problem is that I need to do some complicated ssh tunelling to get access to it as access to the machine is blocked from the outside and some ports are also blocked internally.  So I do the following.

```
ssh -v -L 1200:serverC:22 user@serverB (locally)
ssh -v -L 5900:127.0.0.1:5900 -p 1200 user_from_serverC@127.0.0.1 (locally)
x11vnc -safer -localhost -nopw -once -display :0 (on serverC)
vinagre localhost::5900 (locally)
```

I then run firefox (say) in the vnc window that opens and it all works.

However I would like to have a bash script that does this for me. How can I automate it?

There are two problems.

1. I need to stay logged in after each ssh above for the tunelling to work so a simple bash script just stops after the first step.
2. I don't know how to get an application to run automatically in a vnc window.

Ideally I would just type "./remote-firefox" (for example) locally to get all this to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
x11vnc -safer -localhost -nopw -once -display :0 #Run manually on system_C
```

& on local system,

```
ssh -t -L 5902:localhost:5901 user_B@server_B 'ssh -t -L 5901:localhost:5900 user_C@server_C' &
#Note: Enable password-less (key based) authentication from "your_pc -> servB" & "servB -> servC"

vncviewer localhost:2 #Run on local system
```

**NOTE:** If the commands fail, please try changing the port numbers.
In this example, I am trying to tunnel it as below:

```
your_PC:5902 <-> server_B:5901 <-> server_C:5900
```

---

I have not tested this 2 level chain (I do not know if x11vnc's `-display` parameter works across ssh, but I think, it should.):

```
#Run both lines on local system
ssh -t -L 5902:localhost:5901 user_B@server_B "ssh -t -L 5901:localhost:5900 user_C@server_C 'x11vnc -safer -localhost -nopw -once -display :0'" &
vncviewer localhost:2
```

**EDIT:**
To accomodate this:

> > yes that's it. But annoyingly servB -> servC has port 5900 blocked. – Anush

```
#Run both lines on local system. This may be overhead, but should work.
ssh -t -L 5902:localhost:5901 user_B@server_B "ssh -t -L 5901:localhost:1200 user_C@server_C 'ssh localhost -L 1200:localhost:5900 & x11vnc -safer -localhost -nopw -once -display :0'" &
vncviewer localhost:2
```

Comment: Which part do I replace with that?

Comment: My understanding is this: You have a local linux system & you want to view vnc of a remote linux system. If yes, the 2 commands should suffice your requirement, to replace all 4 commands. If your vncviewer supports `-via` parameter, it will do the tunnelling business behind the scenes.

Comment: Ah no. The problem is that I can't access the remote system directly and in fact I can't even access 5900 from the intermediate machine. This is why I have to do this complicated tunelling.

Comment: can you ssh remote system? or is it a 2 hop case?

Comment: 2 hops always . I should say my method works. I just want to automate in a bash script somehow.

Comment: So it's `your_pc <-> servB <-> servC (vncserver)`?

Comment: yes that's it. But annoyingly servB -> servC has port 5900 blocked.

Comment: Thanks! Why do you use different ports for each computer out of interest? I mean why not have ssh -t -L 5901:localhost:5901 user_B@server_B 'ssh -t -L 5901:localhost:5901 user_C@server_C'  ?

Comment: You can generally, but just wanted to make sure... if serv_b also has vnc running (by default on 5900), then port formwarding may fail...